# Select statement that concatenates the first character after every '/' character in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am trying to write a query which, among other things, brings back the first character in a Varchar field, then returns the first character which appears after each / character throughout the rest of the field.

The field I am refrering too will contain a group of last names, separated by a '/'. For example: `Fischer-Costello/Korbell/Morrison/Pearson`

For the above example, I would want my select statement to return: FKMP.

So far, I have only been able to get my code to return the first character + the first character after the FIRST (and only the first) '/' character.

So for the above example input, my select statement would return: FK

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
select rp.CONTACT_ID, ra.TRADE_REP, c.FIRST_NAME, c.LAST_NAME, 
UPPER(LEFT(FIRST_NAME, 1)) + SUBSTRING(c.first_name,CHARINDEX('/',c.first_name)+1,1) as al_1,
UPPER(LEFT(LAST_NAME, 1)) + SUBSTRING(c.LAST_name,CHARINDEX('/',c.LAST_name)+1,1) as al_2


from dbo.REP_ALIAS ra
inner join dbo.REP_PROFILE rp on rp.CONTACT_ID = ra.CONTACT_ID
inner join dbo.CONTACT c on rp.CONTACT_ID = c.CONTACT_ID

where 
rp.CRD_NUMBER is null and
ra.TRADE_REP like '%DNK%' and
(c.LAST_NAME like '%/%' or c.FIRST_NAME like '%/%') and
ra.TRADE_FIRM in 
(
'xxxxxxx',
'xxxxxxx'
)
```

If you read the code, it's obvious that I am attempting to perform the same concatenation on the first_name column as well. However, I realize that a solution which will work for the Last_name column (used in my example), will also work for the first_name column.

Thank you.

Comment: Will your data for the last name field always consist of four names separated by three slashes?

Comment: No, the number of names will vary with each new record.

Comment: You should fix your design so multiple names aren't stored in a single column.

Comment: I would if I could, trust me. But the fact of the matter is that this is a giant enterprise size database which has been around for a very long time, and I don't have the authority to make changes like that.

Comment: @MartinSmith makes an excellent point, but I guess you are stuck with it...  I'd look into a user-defined function the splits the string and nabs the first char of each element of the split.  There are numerous SO questions about splitting strings in tsql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some default values

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(50) = 'Fischer-Costello/Korbell/Morrison/Pearson'
DECLARE @SplitOn CHAR(1) = '/'
```

This area just splits the string into a list

```
DECLARE @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Value nvarchar(4000)
) 

While (Charindex(@SplitOn, @List)>0)
Begin  

Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
Select 
    Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1)))  

    Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn+',')-1,len(@List))
End  

Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))
```

Now lets grab the first character of each name and stuff it back into a single variable

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT SUBSTRING(VALUE,1,1) FROM @RtnValue FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') AS Value
```

Outputs:

```
Value
FKMP
```

Comment: I would just create a split function and then you call that inline in the last call to stuff your data directly from a table.

Comment: The problem here is the looping. Even turning this into a split function it is using a loop. That means slow!!!

Comment: Thank you, this works great for a given string. But I am honestly not sure how to modify it to work with an entire column of [last name's separated by /'s] EDIT- I know see that you meant to turn this into a function to be used in my original query. Great idea, thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, formatting would be easier on the front end, but he wanted this in sql, this split code is from 4guysfromrolla, case to share code that will split an undetermined field without loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this would be a lot faster than looping. What you need is a set based splitter. Jeff Moden at sql server central has one that is awesome. Here is a link to the article. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Now I know you have to signup for an account to view this but it is free and the logic in that article will change the way you look at data. You might also be able to find his code posted if you search for DelimitedSplit8K.

At any rate, here is how you could implement this type of splitter.

```
declare @Table table(ID int identity, SomeValue varchar(50))

insert @Table
select 'Fischer-Costello/Korbell/Morrison/Pearson'

select ID, STUFF((select '' + left(x.Item, 1)
    from @Table t2
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(SomeValue, '/') x
    where t2.ID = t1.ID
    for xml path('')), 1, 0 , '') as MyResult
from @Table t1
group by t1.ID
```